# how to set settings.settings in different deployment environment

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, settings.settings

**Update：(201502260843)**

more detail.

my project is a dll library,i have multiple environments, such as

```
- app.Development.config
- app.Production.config
- app.Test.config
- app.QA.config
...
```

i use vs extension like [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to add different app.config's transform, use different connection strings based on my build configuration.use it like [Web.config transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx).

it work fine, if there is only `app.config`.

but if some string in `app.config` also in `Settings.settings`, e.g.

```
<applicationSettings>
   <Biz.My.MySettings>
      <setting name="SimpleString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>HelloWorld</value>
      </setting>
   </Biz.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

the **`transform`** will not work.it alway use the string in the `Settings.settings`.

somebody know why? and how to solve it?

---

i know i can use vs extensions like ***configuration transform*** or ***slowcheetah*** to transform the ***app.config*** or ***web.config***. because i use **vb.net**, if i declare string in ***settings.settings***, the string in ***app.config*** can not be transform. can i also set ***settings.settings*** in different deployment environment?

Answer (score 0):

App.config is a .xml format

```
 <userSettings>
   <Acron.HotelApplication.My.MySettings>
      <setting name="UserScopeModelConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
      <value />
  </setting>
</Acron.HotelApplication.My.MySettings>
```

I have 2 ConnectionString depending on needs, to connect at server(database) 
what you want ?? expalain in more details..

Comment: And for Multiple Environments I use in My Solution 3 Projects : Development, BetaClientTest, Production.  (with the same content after commit, but with different settings, conenction strings, etc) Every project with it's own app.config